# Remove www and add https in htaccess for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My problem is that I got a loop of redirects when I try to add SSL.

Here is two examples I've tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

I have removed all other content in `htaccess` and stopped WordPress to load to make sure nothing else is causing this. The loop only redirects to the right https URL 50 times and then got killed.

Why can't I get this to work?

Comment: Always define specific virtualhosts, if you did, a single redirect would do the job cleanly and nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to remove `www` and force `https`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.